# Dijkstra Alogrithm code snippet in javascript

Tags: javascript, dijkstra

```
function djikstra(graph, V, src) {
    let vis = Array(V).fill(0);
    let dist = [];
    for(let i=0;i<V;i++)
    dist.push([10000,-1]);
    dist[src][0] = 0;

    for(let i=0;i<V-1;i++){
       let mn = -1;
       for(let j=0;j<V;j++){
          if(vis[j]===0){
             if(mn===-1 || dist[j][0]<dist[mn][0])
                mn = j;
          }
       }

       vis[mn] = 1;
       for(let j=0;j<graph[mn].length;j++){
          let edge = graph[mn][j];
          if(vis[edge[0]]===0 && dist[edge[0]][0]>dist[mn][0]+edge[1]){
              dist[edge[0]][0] = dist[mn][0]+edge[1];
              dist[edge[0]][1] = mn;
          }
       }
    }
    return dist;}
```

In here, **graph** is an adjacency list with a structure (u_vertex,v_vertex,weight), **mn** signifies the current vertices that's visited right now and **graph[mn].length** gives the total number of all the neighboring vertices that's present in the graph, **dist[]** is a storing minimum distance for every vertices in the graph from source node/vertex, **vis** is the visited array which track all the vertices which are visited by putting 1, otherwise 0

My doubt isn't in the Algorithm, it's in the js code. So, in this line of code when,
let edge = graph[mn][j];
what **edge** actually signifies, a variable or an array where **edge[0] = j** and **edge[1] = weight of mn & j vertices**

So that's very confusing to me because I never used JS like I do C++, so in C++ syntax sense that **edge** would represent variable which signifies weight of the edge between **mn & j** vertices but in JS, it's not true. So I need help...

And this is the code of Adjacency list, the graph is created...

```
function createGraph(V,E){
    // V - Number of vertices in graph
    // E - Number of edges in graph (u,v,w)
    let adj_list = []; // Adjacency list
    for(let i = 0 ; i < V ; i++){
        adj_list.push([]);
    }
    for(let i = 0 ; i < E.length ; i++){
        adj_list[E[i][0]].push([E[i][1],E[i][2]]);
        adj_list[E[i][1]].push([E[i][0],E[i][2]]);
    }
    return adj_list;
}
let src = 0;
let V = 9;
let E = [[0,1,4], [0,7,8], [1,7,11], [1,2,8], [7,8,7], [6,7,1], [2,8,2],[6,8,6], [5,6,2], [2,5,4], [2,3,7], [3,5,14], [3,4,9], [4,5,10]];
let graph = createGraph(V,E);
let distances = djikstra(graph,V,0);
console.log(distances);
```

**Snippet of code**

```js
function djikstra(graph, V, src) {
  let vis = Array(V).fill(0);
  let dist = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < V; i++)
    dist.push([10000, -1]);
  dist[src][0] = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < V - 1; i++) {
    let mn = -1;
    for (let j = 0; j < V; j++) {
      if (vis[j] === 0) {
        if (mn === -1 || dist[j][0] < dist[mn][0])
          mn = j;
      }
    }

    vis[mn] = 1;
    for (let j = 0; j < graph[mn].length; j++) {
      let edge = graph[mn][j];
      if (vis[edge[0]] === 0 && dist[edge[0]][0] > dist[mn][0] + edge[1]) {
        dist[edge[0]][0] = dist[mn][0] + edge[1];
        dist[edge[0]][1] = mn;
      }
    }
  }
  return dist;
}

function createGraph(V, E) {
  // V - Number of vertices in graph
  // E - Number of edges in graph (u,v,w)
  let adj_list = []; // Adjacency list
  for (let i = 0; i < V; i++) {
    adj_list.push([]);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < E.length; i++) {
    adj_list[E[i][0]].push([E[i][1], E[i][2]]);
    adj_list[E[i][1]].push([E[i][0], E[i][2]]);
  }
  return adj_list;
}
let src = 0;
let V = 9;
let E = [
  [0, 1, 4],
  [0, 7, 8],
  [1, 7, 11],
  [1, 2, 8],
  [7, 8, 7],
  [6, 7, 1],
  [2, 8, 2],
  [6, 8, 6],
  [5, 6, 2],
  [2, 5, 4],
  [2, 3, 7],
  [3, 5, 14],
  [3, 4, 9],
  [4, 5, 10]
];
let graph = createGraph(V, E);
let distances = djikstra(graph, V, 0);
console.log(distances);
```

Comment: Why do you think this means something different than it would in C++? It's a straight-forward assignment, which takes the value of `graph[mn][j]` and puts it in the variable `edge`.

Comment: No...if you see it closely, you can see edge[0] and edge[1] is used which makes me think that how come edge becomes an array...right

Comment: `edge` is an array, because `graph[mn][j]` is an array. That's just because of how `graph` is structured, which you don't show us; nothing to do with C++ vs JS.

Comment: Because graph is a 3D array.

Comment: You could also post the (correct) corresponding C++ code. If you want us to compare the two. But in this case C++ and JavaScript  syntax is very much alike.

Comment: @IMSoP yeah...sorry. Now I posted the code snippet, how graph is created.

Comment: We've answered your question. You misunderstand the code. It's basically no different to what it would look like in C++. Did you have a follow-up question?

Comment: @IMSoP So E is the array which contains elements in the form, (u_vertex,v_vertex,weight), like this...let E = [[0,1,4], [0,7,8], [1,7,11], [1,2,8], [7,8,7], [6,7,1], [2,8,2],
    [6,8,6], [5,6,2], [2,5,4], [2,3,7], [3,5,14], [3,4,9], [4,5,10]];

Comment: @jarmod I don't think that graph is a 3D array, it's the array of list, where graph[u] contains (v,w) pair element and that's how the graph is created

Comment: Look at how adj_list is created and populated. It's initialized to [] so it starts at 1D. Then V empty arrays are pushed onto it, so it's now 2D. Then an array of pairs such as `[E[i][1],E[i][2]]` is pushed onto the 2D array at `adj_list[E[i][0]]`. So now it's 3D.

Comment: Please update your question with the ONE issue/challenge here for which you desire an answer.  This should indicate how we can determine proper results (answer) to construct for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with JS vs C++, it's just the way the implementation works.

The main reason it's not obvious is that the code is written with a horrible lack of whitespace or meaningful variables. This is actually a really good example of why coding style is so important.

The list is first initialised as a list of arrays:

```
let adj_list = [];
for(let i = 0 ; i < V ; i++){
    adj_list.push([]);
}
```

Then the items in `graph` are added in these two lines:

```
adj_list[E[i][0]].push([E[i][1],E[i][2]]);
adj_list[E[i][1]].push([E[i][0],E[i][2]]);
```

Tidied up with some meaningful names and intermediate variables, that's:

```
let adj_list = [];

for(let vertex_number = 0 ; vertex_number < number_of_vertices ; vertex_number++){
   adj_list[ vertex_number ] = [];
}

for(let edge_number = 0 ; edge_number < edge_list.length ; edge_number++) {
   let edge = edge_list[edge_number];
   let start = edge[0], end = edge[1], weight = edge[2];
   
   adj_list[ start ].push( [end, weight] );
   adj_list[ end ].push( [start, weight] );
}
```

So:

- `adj_list` is an array with `number_of_vertices` items
- each item in `adj_list` is an array of edges
- each edge is an array with two items
- the first item in each edge is a vertex number (`start` or `end`)
- the second item in each edge is a weight

In the later loop:

- `mn` is the vertex number, so `adj_list[mn]` is an array of edges
- `j` is the edge number in that array, so `adj_list[mn][j]` is an edge
- the edge is assigned to a variable called `edge`
- that edge is an array with two items in it

Again, we can tidy up the variable names, starting by renaming `mn` as `current_vertex`, and introducing some extra variables to make the loop readable:

```
let current_edge_list = graph[current_vertex];
for(let edge_number=0; edge_number < current_edge_list.length; edge_number++) {
   let edge = current_edge_list[edge_number];
   let edge_end=edge[0], edge_weight=edge[1];
   if(
      vis[edge_end] === 0 
      && 
      dist[edge_end][0] > dist[current_vertex][0] + edge_weight
   ) {
      dist[edge_end][0] = dist[current_vertex][0] + edge_weight;
      dist[edge_end][1] = current_vertex;
   }
}
```

We could do similar cleanup on all the other code, and give `vis` and `dist` better names. If we wanted to take more advantage of the language, we could also use objects rather than 2-element arrays for the edges, so that `edge[1]` could be written `edge.weight`.

Comment: So now I posted the full code of Dijkstra algorithm again (edited) and I think that it is most probably, [end, weight]

Comment: Can we write, let edge = graph[mn]; instead of, let edge = graph[mn][j];

Comment: @codosopher No, `graph[mn]` is not a single edge, it's a list of edges. I've expanded more code in my answer. Again, this is nothing to do with JS vs C++, it's just a really good example of why clear code is important.

Comment: maestro, I'm actually making one small prototype as my own pet project similar like google maps, that's the inspiration I'd say and in my pet project, I have used bus and plane as a mode of transportation but the project slightly interesting and different and not just a greedy problem because in this project, when we find a optimal path from source to destination, there is a constraint I've added that we can take a plane as a mode of transportation only once, instead of always taking least time path...so can you help if I stuck in middle of the project....thank you.

Comment: @codosopher That's not really how this site works - take the [tour] if you haven't already. If this answers the question on this page, you can mark it as "accepted" with the big tick on the left. If you get stuck on something else, you can ask a new question on a new page, and different people might be able to help you. Remember to look for existing questions as well.